# Windows CMD History from Memory Dump w/ Volatility

Tags: windows, cmd, netcat, computer-forensics, volatility

I'm trying to analyze a Windows 7 memory dump with Volatility. The goal is to see the CMD commands which were run before the dump was taken.

I ran the following command(output below): 
`volatility.exe --profile=Win7SP1x64_23418 -f WINDOWS7-20200221-214526.raw cmdscan`

I need to figure out what commands were run in the middle chunk (from ncat.exe).

Are there any other Volatility parameters/commands that will output the info as text? Is there any better way to find this information? I have access to the Win7 VM (virtualbox) with a live snapshot allowing me to resume the machine from right before the memory dump was taken.

```
Volatility Foundation Volatility Framework 2.6
**************************************************
CommandProcess: conhost.exe Pid: 2580
CommandHistory: 0x63bf0 Application: cmd.exe Flags: Allocated
CommandCount: 0 LastAdded: -1 LastDisplayed: -1
FirstCommand: 0 CommandCountMax: 50
ProcessHandle: 0x60
Cmd #15 @ 0x30158: 
Cmd #16 @ 0x4ed50: 
**************************************************
CommandProcess: conhost.exe Pid: 2580
CommandHistory: 0x63e40 Application: ncat.exe Flags: Allocated
CommandCount: 0 LastAdded: -1 LastDisplayed: -1
FirstCommand: 0 CommandCountMax: 50
ProcessHandle: 0x58
Cmd #41 @ 0x300f8: 
Cmd #42 @ 0x300f8: 
Cmd #43 @ 0x30060: 
Cmd #44 @ 0x30060: 
**************************************************
CommandProcess: conhost.exe Pid: 3136
CommandHistory: 0x24ec00 Application: DumpIt.exe Flags: Allocated
CommandCount: 0 LastAdded: -1 LastDisplayed: -1
FirstCommand: 0 CommandCountMax: 50
ProcessHandle: 0x60
Cmd #15 @ 0x210158: $
Cmd #16 @ 0x24d570: $
```

Comment: Simple console programs such as cmd.exe and, I assume, ncat.exe don't track their own input history. It's managed by the cooked read in the console host process, conhost.exe. I guess you have a full system dump that has information about conhost.exe instances, but apparently it's not finding any commands. I've never used Volatility, but according to this [cheat sheet](https://www.andreafortuna.org/2017/07/03/volatility-my-own-cheatsheet-part-2-processes-and-dlls), the cmdscan plugin looks for a MaxHistory landmark, and there's a `max_history` parameter if it's not the assumed default value.